# HTTP Failure in Axios for REST api GET

Tags: http, react-native, redux, get, axios

I'm new to react-native and when I trying to get data from RESR api and it nicely work for github api, I used following example for developing

https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29

And I change this for get from another from REST api it shows that following error

```
HTTP Failure in Axios [Error: Network Error]
 Object {
   "error": Object {
     "data": "Network Error",
     "status": 0,
   },
   "meta": Object {
     "previousAction": Object {
       "payload": Object {
         "request": Object {
           "url": "/XXXX/list",
         },
       },
       "type": "my-awesome-app/repos/LOAD",
     },
   },
 "type": "my-awesome-app/repos/LOAD_FAIL",
}
```

Do you guys have any idea

Comment: Can you provide that another rest api `url` and also are you testing on ios?

Comment: https://dog.ceo/dog-api/ this the api

Comment: yes Im testing on ios

Comment: @PritishVaidya when I test this api on ssl certificate checks it fails. is that the problem here ? if it is the problem how can I figure it out

Comment: Seems to run fine, can you edit your question for the `code` that you're using or provide with a working [snack snippet](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: OK I will , this is the tutorial I did and this is working after change only the url it is not working https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29 any way I will add snippet here

Comment: Sorry for the disturbing you I think it is some error on my office PC with the VPN its working in snippet nicely here but scorlling is not happen this is the snippet https://snack.expo.io/HJ8Pt2VoG

Comment: I've also set up a working repo with the example [here](https://github.com/pritishvaidya/Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the `url` config that you're trying to use in the [`tutorial`](https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29) that you've mentioned.

*I'm using this `api` from the docs `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images`*

As per the `tutorial` and the `comments` that you've mentioned here are the *relevant changes for the api and the reducers*

**App.js**

```
// Changing the URL here
const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://dog.ceo/',
    responseType: 'json'
});
```

**HoundsList.js**

```
class HoundsList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.listHounds('hound');
    }
    renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
        </View>
    );
    render() {
        const { hounds } = this.props;
        return (
            <FlatList
                styles={styles.container}
                data={hounds}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        hounds: state.hounds.message
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    listHounds
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HoundsList);
```

**reducer.js**

```
export const GET_HOUNDS = 'my-awesome-app/hounds/LOAD';
export const GET_HOUNDS_SUCCESS = 'my-awesome-app/hounds/LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const GET_HOUNDS_FAIL = 'my-awesome-app/hounds/LOAD_FAIL';

export default function reducer(state = { hounds: [] }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_HOUNDS:
            console.log('Loading')
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case GET_HOUNDS_SUCCESS:
            console.log('Success')
            return { ...state, loading: false, hounds: action.payload.data };
        case GET_HOUNDS_FAIL:
            console.log('failure')
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: 'Error while fetching hounds list'
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function listHounds(breed_name) {
    return {
        type: GET_HOUNDS,
        payload: {
            request: {
                url: `/api/breed/${breed_name}/images`
            }
        }
    };
}
```